# React Rerenders Child Component After State Change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a component in React which renders `@material-ui` table (accessed via React Router if it matters). Inside the table I have a `react-select` dropdown menu which is however rendered via separate component. Here's the code for that parent component:

```
return(
        <>
            <Table aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <StyledTableCell align="center"><GameTypeSelector onGameTypeChange={setSelectedGameType} gameTypes={gameTypes} /></StyledTableCell>

...
```

Obviously the `GameTypeSelector` which I will get to in a second renders the dropdown and the `gameTypes` contains the options for it. `setSelectedGameType` is supposed to update a local state variable which will hold the new value every time the drop down changes:

```
const [selectedGameType, setSelectedGameType] = useState(null);
```

So the last thing is that other component itself. It is pretty much straight forward as well:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({ value: "", label: "Please select game type" });
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    //set options here
}, [props]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in use effect of gamte type selectedo");
    props.onGameTypeChange(selected.value);
}, [selected.value, props]);

return (
    <>
        <Select
            value={selected}
            onChange={selectedOption => setSelected({ value: selectedOption.value, label: selectedOption.label })}
            options={[{ value: null, label: "All" }, ...options]}
        />
    </>
);
```

The weirdest thing happens when I change the value from the drop down. It updates the local `selected` and then calls the function from the parent controller. That function on its turn updates the `selectedGameType` which is still fine and working as expected.

However, after that update it goes and rerenders the `GameTypeSelector` in the table once more and it then sets the `selected` value inside to the default which comes from this line `useState({ value: "", label: "Please select game type" });`. After that the parent value of `selectedGameType` is also set to nothing.

In the browser it looks like this: I select a value from the drop down, it sets it inside of it, updates parent component (figured that much via different console logs) and then resets the `GameTypeSelector` component and it goes to its default value. It only rerenders that single part, the rest of the table stays the same and does not rerender and there is nothing in the code touching the `selectedGameType` anywhere else.

Any idea what's wrong? I guess I am missing something crucial here but I can't figure out what?

Comment: If you could set up a codesnippet or sandbox it would make this easier to understand. Just looking at this from the surface it seems you have two separate state hooks keeping track of the same chunk of data, which is the game type that is selected, right? One of them is in the parent, one of them is in the child...

I would say that the child is rerendering because of the parent's state being changed by the child. A hacky solution could be to add another prop to your GameTypeSelector that will pass what the current selection is, and then use that prop as useState default.

Comment: In your parent component:  
`<GameTypeSelector onGameTypeChange={setSelectedGameType} gameTypes={gameTypes} selectedGameType={selectedGameType} />`  
  
In your child component: `const [selected, setSelected] = useState(props.selectedGameType || { value: "", label: "Please select game type" })`

Comment: Ok I can see where the issue is but your suggestion did not work - it behaves the same way I described. I need the value from the drop down in the parent component to do API calls so I need to have a reference of it there... Any smarter way to approach this whole problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how React is supposed to work, if you set the component to a state then it will always show that state, you need to implement methods to handle the change and update the state as needed.  See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) link

Comment: Can you provide example of such methods? I understand that this is how React is supposed to work and I would get rid off one of the values if I could but I can't figure out how. I need the state value in the parent component as I then use it to make API calls, etc. And I think I need the `selected` variable in the child component in order to simply update the drop down menu and display the proper selection inside of it?